# redirect to a page without changing the url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a wordpress site installed on **mywebsite.com/fr/**
i want the page **mywebsite.com/fr/testpage/** to redirect to **mywebsite.com/fr/pagewithweirdurl/** but still showing in the url **mywebsite.com/fr/testpage/**
i found plugins that redirect fine, but it always changes the url.
i found many htaccess codes in here that do what i want, but they do it for the entire website, i just need these specific pages to do what i want . the rest is fine.

so if someone could help me with an htaccess code and show me how to change the urls in the code for the pages i want i would really appreciate it. 
if you know a plugin that does the redirection whilst keeping the url and not changing it im interested too.

Comment: If you want to keep the url then you should show mywebsite.com/fr/testpage/ in an iframe.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171293/mod-rewrite-forwarding-without-changing-url

Comment: I think you are confused about what a redirect is: if your redirect the user then the URL will change: if the ystay on the same URL they were not redirected.

Comment: I think you can set as alternate url on this page only with the help of this plugin <code>http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/</code>

Comment: i used the page as an iframe thanks subin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^fr/testpage/?$ /fr/pagewithweirdurl/ [NC,L]
```

The key here is not use the `[R]` flag for the rewrite rule which causes an external redirection and changes the URL in the browser's address bar. This assumes that `/fr/testpage/` doesn't exist physically. If you're trying to redirect an existing file/directory remove the two `RewriteCond`itions.